# Can I pray to Navagrahas at night like 7:00-9;00?

Tags: mantras, worship, time, navagraha

Can I pray to Navagrahas after dark or is it inauspicious? Please give scriptural references.

Comment: The phalashruti of navagraha stotram attributed to Vedavyasa ji says that 'diva va yadi va raatro vighnashantirbhavishyati' . So yes you can pray at night (if you consider this as a scriptural reference then yes you can pray) .

Comment: Yes, I do please give a full answer if you can. :)